# tags are not getting displayed in template, Django

Tags: django

```
 context['d_tags'] = Blog.objects.filter(is_published=True).values('tags__name').order_by('tags__name').distinct()
        print(context['d_tags'])
```

this prints the out put as below

```
<QuerySet [{'tags__name': 'ev'}, {'tags__name': 'yoga'}]>
```

how can I show it on templates, tried the following way

```
 {% for tag in d_tags.all %}
                    <li>{{ tag }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
```

gives an out put in template as

```
 {'tags__name': 'ev'}
{'tags__name': 'yoga'}
```

but if I do this way

```
{% for tag in d_tags.all %}
                        <li>{{ tag.name }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
```

doesn't gives any thing in display, how I can get just the values in template

Comment: My first reaction would be trying it like this: 
{% for tag in d_tags.all %}
                        <li>{{ tag.tags__name}}</li>
{% endfor %} don't think it'll work but who knows, you will spend 3 seconds trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said #root's solution doesnt work, but it should... Are you sure you tried {{tag.tags__name}} and not something else?

Another solution would be opening double for loops...

```
 {% for tag in d_tags %}
 {% for tag_name in tag %}
                    <li>{{ tag_name }}</li>
 {% endfor %}                    
{% endfor %}
```

But hey, thats really the same thing as saying {{tag.tags__name}}